# HTML no aplica cambios en estilo boostrap.min.css. Parece leer un SCSS que no puedo editar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, scss

Tengo el siguiente *header* en mi página web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La hoja de estilos es referenciada a un CSS que se encuentra en el servidor, en la ruta definida en href. Al hacer cambios, concretamente en la clase "form-control"(cambio el width a 110% y el tamaño de fuente a 0.9rem). Tras guardar los cambios, borrar caché y recargar página nada cambia. Inspecciono el elemento que quiero cambiar y ver que la clase "form-control" la está encontrando en una ruta que no existe en mi servidor: static/scss/_forms.scss y por lo tanto no tengo acceso a  ella, ni a modificar los parámetros que necesito por asunto de visualización.

Necesito poder acudir a  los css modificables del servidor y no a los scss "remotos".

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he localizado el problema. Resulta que docker no actualiza los cambios en los ficheros .html y .css de la misma forma que hace con el código en Python .py. Para lograr actualizar los cambios en el despliegue de la aplicación se deben tirar y volver a levantar los contenedores (docker-compose down/up) y ya si consigo actualizar los cambios que en el código html y css introduzco.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar `!important` para que se aplique por encima de los estilos de bootstrap mira un ejemplo.

```
.form-control {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

tambien te digo,  si tienes instalado bootstrap con npm (node.json)
accediento a node_modules y luego dist asi:
`<link href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

y el script
`<script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`